# CefSharp/CefSharp.Offscreen/ChromiumWebBrowser ошибка: System.Exception: "Cef can only be initialized once.."

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Хотел параллельно создать и поместить в коллекцию несколько браузеров CefSharp/CefSharp.Offscreen/ChromiumWebBrowser:

```
class TestClass 
{
    List<ChromiumWebBrowser> UnusedBrowsers { get; set; }

    public TestClass ()
    {
        this.UnusedBrowsers = new List<ChromiumWebBrowser>(10);
        Parallel.For(0, 10, (n) => UnusedBrowsers.Add(new ChromiumWebBrowser()));
    }
}
```

в результате получил исключение:

> System.Exception   HResult=0x80131500   Сообщение = Cef can only be
>   initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this
>   exception.   Источник = CefSharp.Core

Как заставить этот код работать? Если есть возможность, прокомментируйте причину ошибки.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ:
Если я вызываю `var br = new ChromiumWebBrowser();` перед `Parallel.For` то никаких ошибок нет. Все отрабатывает нормально.

```
class TestClass 
{
    List<ChromiumWebBrowser> UnusedBrowsers { get; set; }

    public TestClass ()
    {
        this.UnusedBrowsers = new List<ChromiumWebBrowser>(10);

        var br = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        Parallel.For(0, 10, (n) => UnusedBrowsers.Add(new ChromiumWebBrowser()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cef can only be initialized once. Перевод: Сефшарп, может быть инициализирован единожды.

Comment: @Yami Не понятно почему если я перед Parallel.For создам два браузера var br = new ChromiumWebBrowser();, то как результат оба браузера будут созданы (по логике вещей я должен был бы снова ошибку получить) + Parallel.For отработает нормально.

Comment: В каждом потоке, или что там использует класс паралелей, создается новый экземпляр.